# Cbind on multiple file generated through a process generate #NA data

Tags: r, loops, cbind

The program browse through all the files in a folder, process them and cbind them in a single file :

```
files=list.files(path="path", recursive=T, pattern='.xlsx')
for(i in 1:length(files))  
{
#some process goes which generates qs_30 for each file as the loop is run

if (!exists("dataset")){
    dataset <- qs_30
  }

  # if the merged dataset does exist, append to it
  if (exists("dataset")){
    temp_xts <-qs_30
    dataset<-cbind(dataset, temp_xts)
    rm(temp_xts)
  }
}
```

The final data set shows a large table with lot of #NA's. there is no #NA in qs_30 files. Please help in applying cbind on qs_30, which is generated each time the loop is iterated.
Also, is there any other more efficient way to cbind these qs_30.

Comment: @Heroka No dear...qs_30 is completely populated with values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rather generate all the `data.frames` in a list and then `cbind` them in one shot at the end:

```
files = list.files(path="path", recursive=T, pattern='.xlsx')
lst   = lapply(files, function(x) {
    #some process goes which generates qs_30 for each file as the loop is run
    qs_30
}

do.call(cbind, lst)
```

This allows also you to decompose the process of generating data.frames and aggregating them, easier in case of debugging.

Comment: I tried doing this ..processLIQ <- function(input_files[[i]])
{ Some process which generates qs_30}..the error is Error: unexpected '[[' in "processLIQ <- function(input_files[["..I dont know how to pass file reference to a function.

Comment: instead of the commentary, try `processLIQ(x)` since `lapply` take each element of `files`, referred as `x` and process them through the function you define.

Comment: ..I tried but goes to the debugger and shows the error: function (path, sheet = 1, col_names = TRUE, col_types = NULL, 
    na = "", skip = 0) 
{
    path <- check_file(path)
    ext <- tolower(tools::file_ext(path))
    switch(excel_format(path), xls = read_xls(path, sheet, col_names, #shows error
        col_types, na, skip), xlsx = read_xlsx(path, sheet, col_names, 
        col_types, na, skip))
} Also, Browse[1]> do.call(cbind, lst)
Error during wrapup: object 'lst' not found

Comment: you should show your code processing and giving q_30s. Like this we cannot help more. By the way are you sure to understand lapply function correctly?

Comment: Thanks dear..Now I am able to do it :)